# Count rows by time interval of 10 minutes postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i've been trying to find a solution for this query but i'm hitting the wall from the begining i'm trying to count the number of bought and sold items per 10 mins intervals

`date_action          ACTION
2018-03-16 00:00:00    bought
2018-03-16 00:03:00    sold
2018-03-16 00:04:00    bought

2018-03-16 00:27:00    sold

2018-03-16 00:29:00    sold`

the output that i'm trying to get should be something like that

`time_interval         ACTION count
2018-03-16 00:00:00    bought 2
2018-03-16 00:00:00    sold   1
2018-03-16 00:20:00    bought 1
2018-03-16 00:20:00    sold   2`

 i'm new to stack overflow so i hope that my uestion is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncating to 10 minute intervals takes a bit of work, but here is one method:

```
select (date_trunc(date_action, 'hour') +
        (date_part('minute', date_action) / 6) * interval '10 minute'
       ) as time_interval,
       action, count(*)
from t
group by time_interval, action
order by time_interval, action;
```

Comment: It should be `date_trunc( 'hour',date_action)`